# Four parameters logistic regression derivative

Tags: r, parameters, derivative, sigmoid

Good Evening,

I fitted a four parameter logistic curve using R nls function with the following equation:

y = alpha + lambda/(1+exp(-beta(x-mu))

I would like to determine the maximum slope of this curve and for this I would like to compute the derivative of the function. Do you know how I can find the derivative of this function and use it to determine the maximum slope or the maximum derivative value?

Thank you in advance,

Rohan

I find the regular sigmoid equation y = 1/1+e-x and its derivative but not with the parameters.
I am expecting some help with the derivative of my equation and a piece of script that can help me to find the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that the parameters you have calculated are alpha = 1, lambda = 2, beta = 3 and mu = 4.  Then create the derivative function `fder` and use `optimize` to find its maximum.  Evidently the maximum slope occurs at mu and equals 1.5 or substituting x = mu into the derivative fder we have that the derivative at the maximum equals lambda * beta / 4.

```
fder <- function(x, alpha = 1, lambda = 2, beta = 3, mu = 4) {}
body(fder) <- D(expression(alpha + lambda/(1+exp(-beta*(x-mu)))), "x")
optimize(fder, c(-10, 10), maximum = TRUE)
## $maximum
## [1] 3.99999
##
## $objective
## [1] 1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @G.Grothendieck's answer, here's a logical explanation of why the maximum derivative is `lambda*beta/4`.

- The maximum derivative of the unscaled logistic function is 1/4, at `x=0`
- The maximum derivative of `1/(1+exp(-beta*x))` is `beta/4` at `x=0` (you can look this up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)
- adjusting the midpoint (e.g. `1/(1+exp(-beta*(x-mu)))`) shifts the location of the maximum derivative to `x=mu` but doesn't change its value
- shifting the curve up by adding `alpha` (`alpha + 1/(1+exp(-beta*(x-mu)))`) doesn't change the max slope or its location
- scaling the curve by `lambda` (`alpha + lambda/(1+exp(-beta*(x-mu)))`) scales the max derivative by `lambda` (`beta/4 → lambda*beta/4`)